# What package is suggested to persist linux iptables during restarts?

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, init-script

Since I neet to use some nat feature, provided by linux `iptables` I can set those "*rules*" manually and they work. However after a reboot those "*rules*" are gone.

Having `iptables-save` I can "dump iptables rules" (see [`man iptables-save`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables-save)).
Likewise I can "restore IP Tables" with `iptables-restore` (see [`man iptables-restore`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables-restore) those previously saved rules from the iptables-save output (i.e. having saved it to a file)

The only thing now would be a place in the `init` system (e.g. in `systemd` to carry out this loading and restoring).

The system that I attempt to make this work is CentOS/RHEL. So I naively went to install the package `iptables-services.x86_64` but this does way more than simply restoring the rules once provided at `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`. At least in my case it added own rules that disallowed forwarding, thereby completely undoing the effect I did with my created `nat` table rules, that require forwarding.

Is there a better package I may have overlooked. Or is there a place I can add the respective lines

- at shutdown `iptables-save > [path to iptables save file]`
- at bootup `iptables-restore [path to iptables save file]`

in my distros `init`, i.e. `systemd` (ideally not having to undergo all the way to create service/unit files for this task)

Comment: See [Centos 7 save iptables settings](https://serverfault.com/questions/626521/centos-7-save-iptables-settings).

Comment: I would recommend using `nftables` over `iptables`, `iptables6`, `nattables`..... My rules on debian-10 are in `/etc/nft.d/`. I have a simple `nftables` script in there.

Comment: On CentOS 7, you're supposed to use [FirewallD](https://serverfault.com/questions/623297/firewalld-centos-7-masquerading).